# Problems with displaying modal popups in mobile browser and on resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, modal-popup

I have some problems with a modal popup dialog on a site that I'm building. This is the site: www.notforsale.magalidb.com

**These links all have a modal popup behind them:**

- "Lisez la version en ligne"
- "Read the online version"
- "Conditions"
- "Contactez la redaction"
- "Contacteer de redactie"
- "Contact the redaction"

**The problems:**

1. When I browse to the website via Safari mobile (on iPhone or iPad) and I click on any of the above mentioned links, a popup appears. But when I zoom in, the popup jumps away (mostly to the lower right of the screen). So I can't zoom in on whatever is written in that popup.
2. When I browse to the website via regular browsers such as Safari, Opera, Firefox, Chrome or Internet Explorer (didn't test on IE though), and I click on "Bekijk de online versie", then I get to see a larger popup that holds a magazine which can be flipped like a book. If I then resize the browser window, this popup jumps to the lower right of the screen. I then have to close the popup and reopen it in order to see it centered again.

**What I want:**

1. What do I need to edit in my existing code to make my popups remain centered? Even in mobile browsers?
2. How do I prevent this particular popup from jumping to the corner of the browser? I didn't write it differently than the other popups, the only difference is the width and height. But I don't see why it always jumps away, unlike the other popups...

If anyone has a possible solution, please do share. This is quite urgent, since I find that my client deserves a website that functions correctly.

**The code: popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
//select all the a tag with name equal to modal
$('a.modal').click(function(e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    //Get the A tag
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height() ;
    var winW = $(window).width() ;

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('margin-top',  winH / 2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('margin-left', winW / 2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
});

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});         

$(window).resize(function () { 
    var box = $('#boxes .window');

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    box.css('margin-top',  winH/2 - box.height()/2);
    box.css('margin-left', winW/2 - box.width()/2);
});
    });
```

**The code (example, please see site source for full code): index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>NOTFORSALE, the most exclusive car magazine</title>
<link href="stylesheets/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- jQuery library: -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Cycle plugin: -->
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/launch_scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="main-container">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="content-left">
                    <div class="box" id="box1">FR</div>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#dialogFR" class="modal">
                    Telechargez pour iPad ou Android tablet</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#dialogFR" class="modal">Lisez la version en ligne</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-center">
                    <div class="box" id="box2">NL</div>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="scripts/notforsale_DL_NL.php" target="_blank">
                    Download voor iPad of Android tablet</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#dialogNL" class="modal">Bekijk de online versie</a>
                </div>
                <div class="content-right">
                    <div class="box" id="box3">EN</div>
                    <br><br>
                    <!-- 
                    <a href="scripts/notforsale_DL_EN.php" target="_blank">
                    -->
                    <a href="#dialogEN" class="modal">
                    Download for iPad or Android tablet</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="#dialogEN" class="modal">Read the online version</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

!-- From here, the popups start -->
    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="dialogFR" class="window popup-windows" style="width: 600px !important; height: 250px !important;">
            <a href="#" class="close"><img class="cbc" src="images/close.png" alt="close"></a>
            <?php include 'comingsoonFR.php'; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="dialogNL" class="window popup-windows" style="width: 1200px !important; height: 510px !important;"> 
            <a href="#" class="close"><img class="cbm" src="images/close.png" alt="close"></a>
            <?php include 'magazineNL.php'; ?> 
            <div style="z-index:20; margin: -80px; text-align: center;">
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"></a>
                <br>
                <a href="scripts/notforsale_DL_NL.php" target="_blank">Download voor iPad of Android tablet</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dialogEN" class="window popup-windows" style="width: 600px !important; height: 250px !important;">
                <a href="#" class="close"><img class="cbc" src="images/close.png" alt="close"></a>
                <?php include 'comingsoonEN.php'; ?>
        </div>
    <div id="mask"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The code (only showing CSS related to the popups): default.css**

```
/* Popup design */
#mask {
    z-index:9000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    background-color:#000;
    display:none;
}
#boxes .window {
    width: 1200px !important;
    height: 510px !important;
    z-index:9999;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    padding:20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #4D4D4D;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;  
}
.popup-windows{
    background: #4D4D4D !important; 
    border: 1px solid white !important; 
    font-size: 10pt !important; 
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
#boxes #dialog {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.cbm{ /* Short for CloseButtonMagazine */
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: 1196px;
    position: fixed;
}
.cbc{ /* Short for CloseButtonContact */
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I know this might be a lot of text for a question, but I really want to give as much details as I can, in order to make it easier for you to see the whole bundle. As mentioned earlier, you can see the website and test out the popup issues. I use Google Chrome for testing it out, and if all works well there, I check out the site in other browsers to make it compatible.

Also, I think the jumping popup issue is solvable. I saw other tutorials for making modal popups and those work just fine in my mobile browsers, but I can't afford having to recode all those popups. Unless I can edit the existing code and shorten it, while remaining the functionality and without having to edit anything in index.php. Anyway... Please just take a look at it. It might be easier to just meddle with it in-browser, inspecting the elements and such... It's quite a lot of code.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: You need to stop using JavaScript to do visual layout, that's the main issue here. Your questions are a direct result of doing that.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to say here. Why should I stop using JavaScript for this? Do you have a better idea then?

Comment: It's bad practice - you don't need to get widths, height, positions etc. from JavaScript in this case and then apply them to the HTML element inline, this can all be done with fine CSS layout work and would solve the proxy problems you're having issues. "Learn more CSS", I guess that's what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

set your modal popup to position: fixed and height/width 100%, that should cover up the whole screen, and you won't have to worry about window resizing.

for your individual popup boxes, set them to position: fixed as well, and use top/left to position instead of margins. As for zooming, I'd have to see this in action to get a better grasp of the effect you're going for.